# Building a RESTful API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, restful-architecture

I have seen a ton of sites on tutorials and how-to's for building your own RESTFul API using ASP.NET. All of them seem to use MVC though. Is it possible to build my own RESTFul API using ASP.NET and WebForms, without using MVC? If anyone has links to a tutorial or something, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**ASP.NET Web API**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://www.asp.net/web-api&ei=598vUfupH8KUywGN_oDIBA&usg=AFQjCNFlwnk5rGDAU0oVf1CzhM8kgLW9mg&sig2=O69K-e_gAVN3XnLDaY9LJw&bvm=bv.43148975,d.aWc).  It will be the canonical HTTP API server framework moving forward.